# Adding intelligence to Vue JS bot using open source services

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, vue.js, open-source, bots

i am trying to build a bot that is completely open source using Vue JS and i need to add intelligence to make the bot learn from the user input by time and i don't want to use services provided by Microsoft or Google or IBM or any of that i want to use an open source solution that I can host on my own and improve later

how can i do that?

here's how i show hello world now:

```
var botui = new BotUI('hello-world');
botui.message.add({
  content: 'Hello World from bot!'
}).then(function () { // wait till previous message has been shown.
  botui.message.add({
    delay: 1000,
    human: true,
    content: 'Hello World from human!'
  });
});
```

this is what i following rn: https://www.cssscript.com/minimal-javascript-chat-bot-framework-botui/

Comment: This is an incredibly broad question. If you don't want to use a pre-existing service, you're going to have to research machine learning. You may want to re-word and tag your question accordingly.

Comment: @Beau thanks for input but why vote down help me by editing and voting up instead of discouraging me to use the platform not because you don't know the answer vote me down

Comment: Hey @Fegen, you tagged this question as `vue.js`. It's not really related to it, and your question was asking someone how to implement intelligence into your Hello World bot. This is far too vague, and will unlikely get you any answers. As I mentioned in my previous comment, you probably want to research machine learning. a Google of `machine learning open source javascript` yields lots of results. From there if you get stuck implementing it, StackOverflow is definitely the place to ask your questions. I hope this helps!

Comment: @Beau thank you man, will edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AIML:** You can use Artificial Intelligence Markup Language (AIML) to create conversational flows for you bot. AIML is very easy to learn and basically an extension of XML.

**Here is a basic example:**

```
<category> defines beggining of category
<pattern>What the User Says</pattern>
<template>What the Bot Responds</template>
</category>
```

**You can learn more here:** [Playground](https://playground.pandorabots.com/en/tutorial/)

**Open Source Platform for AIML:** [Pandorabots](http://pandorabots.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Open AI is very good as it non profit and allow everything for free https://openai.com/

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are familiar with Python you can checkout Spacy:

https://spacy.io/

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy

They have pretrained word2vec models that you can use and host it on your own server. The library also offers many high level methods that allows you to calculate the similarity between any two sentences. Here is a good web demo of how it works on their website:

https://explosion.ai/demos/similarity

https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity

Once you can find the similarity between sentences all you have to do is store a list of questions and its corresponding answer in a list/database.

Whenever some one asks a new questions, your program will just simply calculate the similarity score with each question stored in the database. It will pick the question with the highest similarity score and return the corresponding answer.

Note this entire library is written in python so you will have to host it on your own and create an API layer on top of it (probably using Flask etc). Then your web app can communicate with it by using the API calls.

They already offer support for a lot of languages out of the box (including english) but you can also train your own custom models.

Here is a sample code example taken from their website:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
doc1 = nlp(u"Hello how are you?")
doc2 = nlp(u"Hi! how are you doing?")
doc1.similarity(doc2)
```